# javascript: (ä=#1={}&&alert)(ä)

Tags: javascript

Found this here http://sla.ckers.org/forum/read.php?2,15812,page=2

If you copy the title of the question and run it in the browser you should see that it's *alerting* the string representation of a function.

```
function alert() {
    [native code]

}
```

Could someone explain slowly what's going on?

Comment: That will do no such thing; it's a syntax error.  The "#" character doesn't have any valid uses in JavaScript (other than *inside* quotes as part of a string constant).

Comment: @Pointy: well, I'm using Firefox 3 on Ubuntu and I assure you that when I paste this to the address bar and run it I get an alert displaying

Comment: # is not a valid character, it can't be used in most javascript engines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with what happens first and workout out from there

1. `{} && alert` — `{}` is true, so `alert` is evaluated and pushed left
2. `#1 = alert` — assign `alert` to the variable `#1` (technically, you aren't allowed to use `#` to start an identifier, but some browsers apparently let you get away with it (ditto `ä`))
3. `ä = #1` — assign `#1` (`alert`) to `ä`
4. `ä(ä)` — call `alert` with `alert` as an argument
5. `alert` automatically calls `theFirstArgument.toString()` which turns the function into a string
6. You then get the rendered string

Comment: thanks David. would you know why in the one-liner form FF would let it work, but not when it's broken down into distinct statements i.e. #1=alert;ä=#1;

Comment: This isn't quite right. `#1` is not a valid identifier, even in Firefox, and `(#1={}&&alert)(#1)` does not work in any browser. The choice of name of `ä` is a red herring: `ä` is in fact a perfectly valid identifier. I'm not sure what's going on with the `#1` bit yet: seems like an oddity of the Firefox parser.